# SharePoint OData filter is not valid

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata

Using this SharePoint OData query:

```
https://{{siteUrl}}/_api/web/lists('{{ListGuid}}')/items?$top=10&$select=Title,CartNum
```

I get the follow in my results:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "32165487-6548-6548-6548-32165498765432",
                    "uri": "<edited>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc')/Items(1)",
                    "etag": "\"183\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.JobsItem"
                },
                "Title": "SomeCart",
                "CartNum": "11047975"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I add a `$filter` option:

```
https://{{siteUrl}}/_api/web/lists('{{ListGuid}}')/items?$top=10&$select=Title,CartNum&$filter=CartNum endswith '11047975'
```

I get this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The expression \"CartNum endswith '11047975'\" is not valid."
        }
    }
}
```

If I change it to:

```
https://{{siteUrl}}/_api/web/lists('{{ListGuid}}')/items?$top=10&$select=Title,CartNum&$filter=CartNum eq '11047975'
```

I get this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service) and [this OData](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption) doc as a reference for the `$filter`, which clearly state:

```
Operator    Description Example
Logical Operators
Eq  Equal   /Suppliers?$filter=Address/City eq 'Redmond'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No endswith based on official documentation.

[image]

When your list data over 5000 items, you can't filter item based on a none-indexed column as throttle limit in SharePoint, you need add the column as indexed so you could filter based on it.

https://collab365.community/working-with-large-lists/

Comment: I just found this while searching for the source of my problem with filter. Could you tell me what the source of this diagram is?